# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS Init Process using all swap space and free memory

Tags: 12.04, server, swap

`Mem:  16402220k total, 16165840k used,   236380k free,   132244k buffers

Swap:  4194296k total,  4191452k used,     2844k free,  1208664k cached`

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
10693 mysql     20   0 12.5g 8.3g 4248 S    3 52.9   6320:38 mysqld
  303 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0 263:23.29 md3_raid1
10120 root      20   0 17340 1236  896 R    0  0.0   0:00.04 top
15434 root      20   0     0    0    0 R    0  0.0   0:37.72 kworker/0:2
    **1 root      20   0 8800m 4.8g  636 S    0 31.0  41:38.48 init**

Anyone have any idea why init is using so much swap space and memory?
How do I begin to debug this, any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much physical memory (pinned) is configured on your machine, but mysqld process (per your ps command output) indicates that it is using 8.3 GB of memory (RES) which is rendering your machine memory-exhausted (swap fully allocated). You may want to investigate your MySQL DBMS. Cheers

Comment: I should have included the mem total line, edited post above<br>
Mem:  16402220k total, 16165840k used,   236380k free,   132244k buffers

Comment: Ok - restarting Mysql (based on your comments) solves the issue. Clearly I don't understand the relationship between init process and started process, so there is some reading in store for me. Thanks for the pointer cogitoergosum